# How to take row from worksheet and paste onto another worksheet row by row

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to vba/coding and I am not sure how to proceed from this point. I am currently trying to copy some columns of a row that matches three of my criteria and paste it on to another worksheet row by row so that it lists out.
I know my logic is all over the place but if I could get some pointers it would be much appreciated.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

Dim Today, EndDate as Date

Dim MainWorksheet as worksheet

Today = Sheets("sheet1").Range("k8").Value
EndDate = Sheets("sheet1").Range("k9").Value

Set MainWorksheet = Worksheets("sheet2")

Dim Name as String

Name = "Condition 1"

a = MainWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUP).Row

For i = 2 to a

    Dim z as boolean
    Dim x as boolean
    Dim c as boolean

    z = Mainworksheet.Cells(i,7).Value >= Today
    x = Mainworksheet.Cells(i,8).Value <= EndDate
    c = Mainworksheet.Cells(i,6).Value = Name

If z And x And c = True Then
    
    MainWorksheet.Rows(i).Range("b1,f1,g1,h1,k1,d1").copy

    worksheets("sheet1").Activate

    Range("k8").Select

        If ActiveCell.Value = "" then

        Activecell.PasteSpecial

            Else

                ActiveCell.offset(1,0).select

                Activecell.PasteSpecial

            End if

       End if

 Next i


End sub
```

Comment: `"b1,f1,g1,h1,k1,d1"` - you can't change the order of the pasted columns by doing this

Comment: There are multiple issues which can be easily solved. If you could confirm that you are trying to write the values to the first available range in `Sheet1` starting from cell `K8`, e.g. if K8 = "" then copy to range `K8:P8`, next match copy to `K9:P9`... etc. or clarify if not.

Comment: hello! that is exactly what i’m trying to do

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Specified Cells (Columns) of Rows

- Although it does the job, it does it slowly.
- Note that if there would be only values (no formulas, formats) needed to be copied, a different solution may increase the speed of execution dozens of times. And further more, implementing arrays may increase the speed of execution probably even hundreds of times.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyReport()
    
    ' Constants
    Const Criteria As String = "Condition 1"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' Workbook containing this code.
    
    ' Source Worksheet
    Dim src As Worksheet: Set src = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    ' Last Row, the row of the last non-empty cell in column 'A'
    Dim srcLast As Long: srcLast = src.Cells(src.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Destination Worksheet
    Dim dst As Worksheet: Set dst = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ' Last Cell, the last non-empty cell in column 'K'
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dst.Cells(dst.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp)
    ' Dates: Start Date, End Date
    Dim sDate As Date: sDate = dst.Range("K8").Value
    Dim eDate As Date: eDate = dst.Range("K9").Value
    
    ' Declare variables.
    Dim rng As Range ' Current Source Range
    Dim sCell As Range ' Current Cell in Current Area of Current Source Range
    Dim i As Long ' Source Rows Counter
    Dim j As Long ' Destination Columns Counter
    Dim bCrit As Boolean ' Criteria Validator
    Dim bStart As Boolean ' Start Date Validator
    Dim bEnd As Boolean ' End Date Validator
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Loop
    For i = 2 To srcLast
        
        bCrit = (src.Cells(i, "F").Value = Criteria)
        bStart = (src.Cells(i, "G").Value >= sDate)
        bEnd = (src.Cells(i, "H").Value <= eDate)
        
        If bCrit And bStart And bEnd Then
            Set rng = src.Rows(i).Range("B1,F1,G1,H1,K1,D1")
            Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1)
            ' You cannot use 'rng.Copy dCell' because it will copy
            ' "B1,D1,F1,G1,H1,K1".
            j = 0
            For Each sCell In rng.Areas
                sCell.Copy dCell.Offset(, j)
                j = j + 1
            Next sCell
        End If
    
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for your answer! It helped me clear where I went wrong and how to set it up better. Just few questions if you don't mind.

It seems I'm getting a Run time error 1004: cant do that to a merged cell in the code
`sCell.Copy dCell.Offset(,j)`

Also there is a graph underneath the range K8:Q26 where I want the rows to be inputted and it seems to be pasting it from the graph's title K27 and below. Would there be a way I can work around this?

Comment: A workaround is not that simple, so I consider it out of the scope of your question. You have a working code now and two reasons why it doesn't work for you: there are merged cells and a chart is in the way. These are the ingredients for a new question, which you should ask and give more accurate information this time e.g. the locations of the merged cells and of the chart and of the result, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't easy to understand what you wanted. I coded the following, hope it helps...

```
Sub New_List()

Dim cond(1 To 3), created As Boolean
Dim db_first_row, db_last_row As Integer
Dim today, endate, name As Integer
Dim paste_row_start, paste_col_start As Integer
Dim data_sheet, target_sheet As String

'CONFIG (MODIFY THIS VARIABLES)

data_sheet = "worksheet2"    'sheet where the conditions and data are
target_sheet = "worksheet1"  'in what sheet do you want to paste?
db_first_row = 1             'in what row dose main table starts?
db_last_row = 10             'in what row dose main table ends?
paste_row_start = 1          'from what ROW would you like to start pasting?
paste_col_start = 2          'from what COL would you like to start pasting?

For db_first_row = 1 To db_last_row
    
    'check conditions
    With Sheets(data_sheet)
    today = .Range("L3")    'where is your condition "today"?
    endate = .Range("L4")   'where is your condition "endate"?
    name = .Range("L5")     'where is your condition "name"?

    cond(1) = .Cells(db_first_row, 7) >= today
    cond(2) = .Cells(db_first_row, 8) <= endate
    cond(3) = .Cells(db_first_row, 6) = name
    End With
    
    'if conditions are met, proceed
    If cond(1) = True And cond(2) = True And cond(3) = True Then
        
        'if you need to create a new worksheet
        'activate this CODE:
        
        'If created = False Then
            'Sheets.Add.name = "NAME OF SHEET"
            'created = True
        'End If
        
        With Sheets(data_sheet)
        Sheets(target_sheet).Cells(paste_row_start, paste_col_start) = _
        .Range("B" & db_first_row)
        Sheets(target_sheet).Cells(paste_row_start, paste_col_start + 1) = _
        .Range("D" & db_first_row)
        Sheets(target_sheet).Cells(paste_row_start, paste_col_start + 2) = _
        .Range("F" & db_first_row)
        Sheets(target_sheet).Cells(paste_row_start, paste_col_start + 3) = _
        .Range("G" & db_first_row)
        Sheets(target_sheet).Cells(paste_row_start, paste_col_start + 4) = _
        .Range("H" & db_first_row)
        End With
    
    paste_row_start = paste_row_start + 1
    
    End If
    
Next db_first_row

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the code! 
What I am trying to achieve with the code is to be able to copy certain columns of a row when they meet the conditions from worksheet2 and paste them row by row to a section I have in worksheet1. I was able to copy one of the rows but couldn't figure out how to make it check each row and paste all of the rows with the matching conditions on to worksheet1 instead of just the one row.

Comment: Hi bro, I modified the code, now is more flexible. It should solve your problem. Good luck!